# Optimizing total for several polynomial functions

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have 4 different power stations. Each power station has its corresponding efficiency function. If I need to produce a specific amount of total power, there will be one (or maybe several) configurations of amount of production for each station that would lead to the greatest possible total efficiency.
I want to find these specific production values for each power station that would lead to this maximum total efficiency. I specify my total power requirement in the code itself.

In my code I have specified each power stations with production amounts and corresponding efficiency values. I am using the "minimize" function from the scipy.optimize module.

The code gives back an answer that might look reasonable at first sight, but it is not necessarily the most optimal solution. For example, the power station "East" has a maximum efficiency of 86.34% at P = 28.52. So if I set 28.52 as the total_effect, the most optimal solution would be to run only power station East at 28.52 MW, and set all the others to 0. This is not the result I get.

How should I change my code? Are there any obvious mistakes? Any other module or function I should use?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# Defining arrays for effevt (P) and efficiency (eta) for each power plant
P_North = np.array([0.11, 0.23, 0.45, 0.75, 1.11, 1.45, 1.75, 2.01, 2.17, 2.30, 2.27])
eta_North = np.array([4.584, 18.362, 32.330, 50.288, 64.760, 74.638, 80.022, 83.494, 84.771, 85.635, 84.254])

P_West = np.array([3.63, 4.59, 5.51, 6.50, 7.35, 8.35, 8.94])
eta_West = np.array([82.717, 83.711, 84.341, 84.629, 83.793, 82.765, 80.756])

P_South = np.array([4.541, 9.181, 13.771, 18.561, 22.971, 27.851, 31.821])
eta_South = np.array([80.3471, 83.1261, 84.3591, 85.4051, 85.6741, 85.6191, 84.4601])

P_East = np.array([18.00, 20.00, 25.00, 32.00, 35.00, 36.00])
eta_East = np.array([81.360, 83.253, 85.589, 85.642, 85.624, 82.931])

tot_names = ["North", "West", "South", "East"]
P_tot = [P_North, P_West, P_South, P_East]
eta_tot = [eta_North, eta_West, eta_South, eta_East]

# Constructing polynomial functions of the efficiency
coefficient = [np.polyfit(P[0:], eta[0:], 2) for P, eta in zip(P_tot, eta_tot)]
polynomal = [np.poly1d(coefficient) for coefficient in coefficient]

min_cost = float('inf')
best_solution = None
total_effect = float(input("How much effect shall be produced this hour?: ")) # MWh
initial_distribution = total_effect / 4

# Defining "neg_function" which is reversly propotional with the sum of all the efficiencies. Goal: maximize total efficiency by minimizing the negative sum of the efficiencies
def neg_function(x):
    efficiencies = [x[i] * polynomal[i](x[i]) for i in range(4)]
    return - sum(efficiencies) / total_effect
    
constraints = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x) - total_effect}]
    
bounds = [(0, max(P)) for P in P_tot]
    
x0 = np.array([min(initial_distribution, max(P)) for P in P_tot])

# No idea if it's necessary to use the SLSQP here. Have tried several different methods
solution = minimize(neg_function, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=constraints, bounds=bounds)
    
if solution.fun < min_cost:
    min_cost = solution.fun
    best_solution = solution

# Print the optimal power outputs for each station
for i in range(len(tot_names)):
    print(f"Optimal effect for {tot_names[i]}: {round(best_solution.x[i], 2)} MW")

# Plotting efficiency curves
P_poly = [np.arange(P[0], P[-1]+0.001, 0.001) for P in P_tot]
eta_poly= [polynomal(P_poly) for P_poly, polynomal in zip(P_poly, polynomal)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 4)

axes = [
    fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0]),
    fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1]),
    fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 2]),
    fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 3]),
]

data = []
for i in range(len(P_tot)):
    data1 = (P_tot[i], eta_tot[i], P_poly[i], eta_poly[i], tot_names[i])
    data.append(data1)

for ax, (x, y, x_int, y_int, title) in zip(axes, data):
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', x_int, y_int, '-')
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel('Effect [MW]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Efficiency [%]')

    # Vertical line at the optimal production level
    index = tot_names.index(title)
    ax.axvline(x=best_solution.x[index], color='b', linestyle='--')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What value would typically go in your `input`?

Comment: Does it make sense for your efficiencies to be extrapolated from the polynomial fit all the way down to both roots (0%)? If not, should you be limiting `total_effect` to only what may be produced as a sum within the limits of `eta` data?

Comment: @Julenissemannen – 
By the way - when calculating with floating point values, due to inexact representation of decimal fractions it is often a mistake to use exact equality comparisons like in the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you do enough to limit your power setting to valid ranges, in several places: in your `input`, as well as in your bounds.

Surely 0 isn't a valid power effect if you don't have any efficiency data for low effect values near 0. I first demonstrate with both lower and upper bounds.

If these bounds are enforced, your distribution of /4 is somewhat clearly invalid, because that will be out of range for some of the power plants.

A cross at the actual value of power and efficiency is more informative than a vertical line, and I don't see much value in separating your subplots by generator - they can go on the same plot, especially if you use semilog.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_data = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [0.11, 0.23, 0.45, 0.75, 1.11, 1.45, 1.75, 2.01, 2.17, 2.30, 2.27],
        'eta': [4.584, 18.362, 32.330, 50.288, 64.760, 74.638, 80.022, 83.494, 84.771, 85.635, 84.254],
        'loc': 'North',
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [3.63, 4.59, 5.51, 6.50, 7.35, 8.35, 8.94],
        'eta': [82.717, 83.711, 84.341, 84.629, 83.793, 82.765, 80.756],
        'loc': 'West',
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [4.541, 9.181, 13.771, 18.561, 22.971, 27.851, 31.821],
        'eta': [80.3471, 83.1261, 84.3591, 85.4051, 85.6741, 85.6191, 84.4601],
        'loc': 'South',
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [18.00, 20.00, 25.00, 32.00, 35.00, 36.00],
        'eta': [81.360, 83.253, 85.589, 85.642, 85.624, 82.931],
        'loc': 'East',
    }),
)
n_loc = len(df_data)
df = pd.concat(df_data)


def do_fit(group: pd.DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    return Polynomial.fit(x=group.P, y=group.eta, deg=2, symbol='P')


by_loc = df.groupby('loc')
min_powers = by_loc.P.min()
max_powers = by_loc.P.max()
min_effect = min_powers.sum()
max_effect = max_powers.sum()
polys = by_loc.apply(do_fit)


while True:
    try:
        total_effect = float(input(f"Power in MW this hour ({min_effect:.3f}-{max_effect:.3f}): "))
        if min_effect <= total_effect <= max_effect:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass


def eval_polys(P: np.ndarray) -> list[float]:
    return [poly(p) for poly, p in zip(polys, P)]


def cost(P: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return -sum(eval_polys(P))


constraints = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.ones(n_loc),
    lb=total_effect, ub=total_effect,
)
bounds = np.stack((min_powers, max_powers), axis=1)

solution = minimize(fun=cost, x0=min_powers, constraints=constraints, bounds=bounds)
assert solution.success, solution.message
optimal_P = pd.Series(data=solution.x, index=polys.index)
optimal_eta = pd.Series(data=eval_polys(optimal_P), index=polys.index)
print('Optimal effect (MW):')
print(optimal_P.to_string(float_format='{:.2f}'.format))
print('Optimal eta:')
print(optimal_eta.to_string(float_format='{:.3f}'.format))

fig: plt.Figure
ax: plt.Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for loc, group in by_loc:
    P = np.linspace(start=min_powers[loc], stop=max_powers[loc], num=100)
    ax.plot(P, polys[loc](P), zorder=1, label=loc + ' (fit)')
    ax.scatter(group.P, group.eta, zorder=2, label=loc + ' (data)')

ax.scatter(optimal_P, optimal_eta, zorder=3, c='black', s=80, marker='+', label='Optimal values')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Effect [MW]')
ax.set_ylabel('Efficiency [%]')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

```
Power in MW this hour (26.281-79.061): 50
Optimal effect (MW):
loc
East    26.12
North    2.14
South   16.09
West     5.66
Optimal eta:
loc
East    86.087
North   84.574
South   85.052
West    84.575
```

[image: fits]

> the power station "East" has a maximum efficiency of 86.34% at P = 28.52. So if I set 28.52 as the total_effect, the most optimal solution would be to run only power station East at 28.52 MW, and set all the others to 0

With the same outcome, perhaps, but with different cost criteria: Thinking about the actual problem at hand, it probably isn't useful to maximize the sum of efficiency values, since they don't have the same weight. Instead you should be *minimizing the total power in* as calculated from the individual efficiencies. Applying this to your figure of 28.52 MW, and changing the assumption to accept 0 as a valid effect, the solution looks more like

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_data = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [0.11, 0.23, 0.45, 0.75, 1.11, 1.45, 1.75, 2.01, 2.17, 2.30, 2.27],
        'eta': [4.584, 18.362, 32.330, 50.288, 64.760, 74.638, 80.022, 83.494, 84.771, 85.635, 84.254],
        'loc': 'North',
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [3.63, 4.59, 5.51, 6.50, 7.35, 8.35, 8.94],
        'eta': [82.717, 83.711, 84.341, 84.629, 83.793, 82.765, 80.756],
        'loc': 'West',
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [4.541, 9.181, 13.771, 18.561, 22.971, 27.851, 31.821],
        'eta': [80.3471, 83.1261, 84.3591, 85.4051, 85.6741, 85.6191, 84.4601],
        'loc': 'South',
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'P': [18.00, 20.00, 25.00, 32.00, 35.00, 36.00],
        'eta': [81.360, 83.253, 85.589, 85.642, 85.624, 82.931],
        'loc': 'East',
    }),
)
n_loc = len(df_data)
df = pd.concat(df_data)


def do_fit(group: pd.DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    return Polynomial.fit(x=group.P, y=group.eta, deg=2, symbol='P')


by_loc = df.groupby('loc')
max_powers = by_loc.P.max()
max_effect = max_powers.sum()
polys = by_loc.apply(do_fit)


while True:
    try:
        total_effect = float(input(f"Power in MW this hour (0-{max_effect:.3f}): "))
        if 0 <= total_effect <= max_effect:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass


def eval_polys(P: np.ndarray) -> list[float]:
    return [poly(p) for poly, p in zip(polys, P)]


def power_in(Pout: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    efficiencies = eval_polys(Pout)
    return Pout / efficiencies * 100


def cost(Pout: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return power_in(Pout).sum()


constraints = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.ones(n_loc),
    lb=total_effect, ub=total_effect,
)
bounds = np.stack((np.zeros(n_loc), max_powers), axis=1)

solution = minimize(fun=cost, x0=np.zeros(n_loc), constraints=constraints, bounds=bounds)
assert solution.success, solution.message
optimal_P = pd.Series(data=solution.x, index=polys.index)
optimal_eta = pd.Series(data=eval_polys(optimal_P), index=polys.index)

print('\nOptimal effect (MW):')
print(optimal_P.to_string(float_format='{:.2f}'.format))

print('\nOptimal eta:')
print(optimal_eta.to_string(float_format='{:.3f}'.format))

fig: plt.Figure
ax: plt.Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for loc, group in by_loc:
    P = np.linspace(start=0, stop=max_powers[loc], num=100)
    ax.plot(P, polys[loc](P), zorder=1, label=loc + ' (fit)')
    ax.scatter(group.P, group.eta, zorder=2, label=loc + ' (data)')

ax.scatter(
    optimal_P.clip(lower=0.01),
    optimal_eta,
    zorder=3, c='black', s=80, marker='+', label='Optimal values')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Effect [MW]')
ax.set_ylabel('Efficiency [%]')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

```
Power in MW this hour (0-79.061): 28.52

Optimal effect (MW):
loc
East    26.46
North    2.06
South    0.00
West     0.00

Optimal eta:
loc
East    86.155
North   84.447
South   77.537
West    70.919
```

[image: clipped]

Comparing your proposed solution with that from the code above via

```py
print(power_in(np.array([26.46, 2.06, 0, 0])).sum())
print(power_in(np.array([28.52, 0, 0, 0])).sum())
```

we get

```
33.151353481691885
33.03046970728739
```

They're pretty close. This can be further tuned by

- adding the Jacobian (which should be simple enough),
- using a global optimizer instead of a local optimizer,
- reducing the number of degrees of freedom by one and removing your constraint,

or better, calculating the minimum analytically since (within bounds) your cost function is continuous and differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an a little different approach that keeps the problem discrete and enumerates the possible solutions exhaustively. This is feasible in that case since there are a mere 3234 combinations. There are inaccuracies in this method that may have be noticeable for too sparse data, but obviously it does not exclude the possibility of fitting polynomials first and then using those to interpolate and then working with the more fine-grained data to dampen this undesired effect. Here, each array of values is made about four times less sparse, giving 946125 combinations and still very small runtime.

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

P_North = [0.11, 0.23, 0.45, 0.75, 1.11, 1.45, 1.75, 2.01, 2.17, 2.30, 2.27]
eta_North = [4.584, 18.362, 32.330, 50.288, 64.760, 74.638, 80.022, 83.494, 84.771, 85.635, 84.254]

P_West = [3.63, 4.59, 5.51, 6.50, 7.35, 8.35, 8.94]
eta_West = [82.717, 83.711, 84.341, 84.629, 83.793, 82.765, 80.756]

P_South = [4.541, 9.181, 13.771, 18.561, 22.971, 27.851, 31.821]
eta_South = [80.3471, 83.1261, 84.3591, 85.4051, 85.6741, 85.6191, 84.4601]

P_East = [18.00, 20.00, 25.00, 32.00, 35.00, 36.00]
eta_East = [81.360, 83.253, 85.589, 85.642, 85.624, 82.931]

tot_names = ["North", "West", "South", "East"]
P_tot_orig = [P_North, P_West, P_South, P_East]
eta_tot_orig = [eta_North, eta_West, eta_South, eta_East]
```

Interpolation:

```
interp_factor = 4

def interpolate(arr, factor):
    n = len(arr) * factor
    return np.arange(min(arr) - 0.001, max(arr) + 0.001, (max(arr) - min(arr)) / n)

coefficient = [np.polyfit(P, eta, 2) for P, eta in zip(P_tot_orig, eta_tot_orig)]
polynomal = [np.poly1d(coefficient) for coefficient in coefficient]

P_tot = [list(interpolate(P, interp_factor)) for P in P_tot_orig]
eta_tot = [list(polynomal(P)) for P, polynomal in zip(P_tot, polynomal)]
```

Optimization:

```
def get_optimal_configuration(total_effect, max_relative_deviation=.05):
    min_P = total_effect
    max_P = total_effect * (1 + max_relative_deviation)
    best_E, best_P = -float('inf'), None
    powers, efficiencies = None, None
    for P_arr, eta_arr in zip(product(*P_tot), product(*eta_tot)):
        P = sum(P_arr)
        if min_P <= P <= max_P:
            E = sum(eta_arr)
            if E > best_E:
                best_P, best_E = P, E
                powers, efficiencies = P_arr, eta_arr
    if best_P is None:
        print(f'No solution for total_effect in ({min_P:.2f}, {max_P:.2f})')
    else:
        p_dist = ", ".join([f'({n}, {p:.2f})' for n, p in zip(tot_names, powers)])
        e_dist = ", ".join([f'({n}, {e:.2f})' for n, e in zip(tot_names, efficiencies)])
        print(
            f'Maximum efficiency of {best_E:.2f}% for total_effect in ({min_P:.2f}, {max_P:.2f}) reached for '
            f'total_effect = {best_P:.2f} and\npowers [{p_dist}] and\nefficiencies [{e_dist}].\n'
        )
    return best_E, best_P, powers, efficiencies
```

Example usage:

```
get_optimal_configuration(60)
```

prints

```
Maximum efficiency of 341.29% for P in (60.00, 63.00) reached for P = 60.58 and
powers [(North, 2.15), (West, 5.90), (South, 24.03), (East, 28.50)] and
efficiencies [(North, 84.57), (West, 84.60), (South, 85.77), (East, 86.34)].

(341.2886446785335,
 60.57911038961039,
 (2.149681818181819, 5.904714285714286, 24.025714285714283, 28.499),
 (84.57391666669983, 84.60418947837982, 85.7660321381848, 86.34450639526902))
```

Explanation:

First, degree-2 polynomials `f(P, eta)` are fitted for each of the four directions. Next, each pair of arrays `(P, eta)` is adjusted by roughly quadrupling (see `interp_factor`) the number of points in the array `P` (keeping the range the same, except for some `buffer`) and applying the obtained polynomials to get the values for `eta`.

The function `get_optimal_configuration` then simply loops through each combination, and picks whichever combination that is above the specified `total_effect` (but no more than `total_effect * max_relative_deviation` above) with the highest sum of efficiencies (which is equivalent to minimizing minus the ratio of sum of efficiencies to total_effect), if there is any such combination.